# Create a search bar in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying create a search bar, when user want to search a product.

Here is my Search Input:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  navigate(`/search/${searchTerm}`);
  setIsShowing(false);
  setOpacity(1);
};

<SearchTitle>What are you looking for?</SearchTitle>
<FormSearch onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <SearchInput type="text" 
               placeholder="Type something to search" 
               onChange={(e)=> setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} 
               defaultValue={searchTerm} />
  <SearchButton type="submit" value="Search" />
</FormSearch>
```

and here is the router when click search and take user to another page:

```
<Router>
  <SearchInfo
    path="/search/:title "
    setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm}
  />
</Router>
```

and here is my react function for the page after search:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
const SearchInfo = (props) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  }, [props]);

  const InfoWrapper = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <InfoWrapper>
        {props === "beuter" ? <h1> Hello World </h1> : <h1>Null</h1>}
      </InfoWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchInfo;
```

Why I typed `beuter` into my search bar and went to the page but it return `Null` instead of `Hello World`?

This is my console show when I `console.log(props)`:

```
{path: "/search/:title ", "title ": "beuter", uri: "/search/beuter",
 location: {…}, setSearchTerm: ƒ, …} children: undefined location:
 {pathname: "/search/beuter", search: "", hash: "", href:
 "http://localhost:3000/search/beuter", origin:
 "http://localhost:3000", …} navigate: ƒ navigate(to, options) path:
 "/search/:title " setSearchTerm: ƒ () "title ": "beuter" uri:
 "/search/beuter"
 __proto__: Object
```

I created Items from mongoose and every item has a title `beuter` in it.

Comment: Is there a reason you are naming the property `"title "`, with a space at the end? I mean, that's fine, it should still work, but it's quite odd.

Answer (score 1):

From your console log props is the entire object what u need is props.title so change your `InfoWrapper` component to this :

```
<InfoWrapper>
  {props.title === "beuter" ? <h1> Hello World </h1> : <h1>Null</h1>}
</InfoWrapper>
```

Comment: It's still return me null but If i tried like this `props = "beuter"` it will show `Hello World`

Comment: Then there is some other error. props = "beuter" is wrong that is not comparison it is assigning value "beuter" to props and it is always true.

Comment: can u try ``props.match.params.title``instead of ``props.title``

Comment: getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

Comment: ok try using useParams provided by react-router-dom ``import { useParams} from "react-router-dom"`` add this inside the SearchInfo Component and `` let { title } = useParams();`` use this to get your title params.

Comment: It would be `props["title "]` since it has a space at the end...

Comment: Oooh I missed that. It might be this.